# Return Every Parent Relationship and filter children in where clause active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a relationship of a Parent, Child, Skills. Each Parent can have several children and each child has one skill.

I want to return all Parents from the database and include the children that belong to them if they have a certain skill.

At the end of the query we will have several parents with possibly 0 children. I'm  trying something like this `Parent.includes(children: [:skill]).where(skill: {skill_type: type})` but this doesn't return all the Parents. Is this possible to do through ActiveRecord?

Comment: Is it really `skillType` and not `skill_type`? The former is very idiosyncratic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
  has_many :skills, through: :children
  def self.with_skill(skill_type)
    children = Child.joins(:skills).where(skills: { skill_type: skill_type } )
    Parent.all.map do |parent|
      children = children.select { |c| c.parent_id == parent.id }
      # This marks the association as loaded so that rails does not issue a n+1 query
      association = parent.association(:children)
      association.loaded!
      association.target.concat(children)
      children.each { |c| association.set_inverse_instance(c) }
      parent.readonly! # because we dont want to accidentally set the children to []
      parent
    end
  end
end
```

Here we use two queries, the first fetches all the children with the selected skill and the skill. The second gets all the parents.

We then manually setup the relation between Parent and Child so that it `parent.children` does not cause ActiveRecord to query the database for children.

We also mark the record as read-only since if one of these records was saved it could remove the `parent_id` from the associated children.

All in all this is a bit of a work-around which will work well for displaying the records. Rails does not really let you pick and choose exactly what associations should be preloaded in the way you would desire here.

Comment: Thanks for this amount of effort. It is close to what I'm looking for except that I always want to return all parents, but if their children don't have the skill don't include them underneath the Parent object. So if Parent 'parent2' has a child with the procrastinating skill and we look for children with 'sneaking' skill it would return parent2 with no children, not an empty active record relation.

Comment: I edited it with a workaround - you could build a `joins` with a custom query but it will still cause a n+1 per Parent due to the way preloading works. I have created a question on whether you could use `eager_load` here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33716153/join-on-and-conditions-when-eager-loading-association-in-activerecord

Comment: Thanks I am playing with the solutions now. I need to be able to return a JSON response and have an empty children array show up for the parent if they don't have any children with a skill. Right now I'm still getting all the results back in the JSON response but may be something dumb I'm doing.

Comment: You can do something like this https://gist.github.com/maxcal/254aaa3cc790d1b8fda0. Not sure of the performance on a large set since you are iterating through the records in Ruby instead of on the database.

Comment: Edited. I used this a while back when I could'nt get Rails to load an association the way I wanted. Its basically how the Rails joins and includes method load associated records.

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly for what I needed to do.