# Eager-load for custom joins in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, eager-loading

I have a table of restaurants that have many reservations. Now I would like to query all restaurants and in case they have reservations for 2 people it should preload these associations. In case there are no reservations for 2 it should still return the restaurants, but with an empty association.

For that I tried the following query:

```
Restaurant.eager_load(:reservations).where("number_of_people = ?", 2)
```

However, this doesn't work, since it discards all restaurants that do have reservations but none of them is for 2 people.

So what I would like to do is moving that condition into the join condition. Something like:

```
Restaurant.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN \"reservations\" ON \"reservations\".\"restaurant_id\" = \"restaurants\".\"id\" AND \"reservations\".\"number_of_people\" = ?', 2)
```

That would give the result I need, however this is not preloading the "reservations" associations but causing an N+1 issue.

It doesn't seem like eager_load accepts custom queries. I found these threads: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12270 and [JOIN ON ... AND conditions when eager loading association in ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33716153/join-on-and-conditions-when-eager-loading-association-in-activerecord) but there is no solution offered.

Comment: you can use `includes`  instead `joins`

Comment: `includes` doesn't accept custom SQL either

Comment: You need to create a new association with the condition

Answer (score 1):

I think Deepak is right.
Try this:

```
 #retaurant.rb
 has_many :reservations_for_two, ->{number_of_people: 2}, class_name: 'Reservation'
```

And then:

```
  Restaurant.preload(:reservations_for_two) #(for two separate queries)
```

OR

```
   Restaurant.eager_load(:reservations_for_two) #(one join query)
```

Comment: I would need this to be dynamic though, where I can specify the `number_of_people` as an argument instead of hardcoding it

Answer (score 1):

Try `Restaurant.joins(:reservations).includes(:reservations).where("reservations.number_of_people = ?", 2)`

Comment: This also only creates a "WHERE" statement and doesn't put it into the "ON" condition.

Comment: Ok I got your question. The second answer is right, as of hard coding the value one dirty hack is to create an class << self level attr_accessor on your model class and assign value before making query like `has_many :reservations_for_x, ->{number_of_people: Restaurant.number_of_people_to_query}, class_name: 'Reservation'` and before eager loading assign your criteria to class attribute.

Comment: That works, but only in a single threaded environment. I am concerned about race conditions given that this uses a class variable.

Comment: Didn't test, but it appears that class level instance variables are thread safe (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558192/thread-safety-class-variables-in-ruby/9558452#9558452). Alternatively you can use `Thread.current[:number_of_people_to_query] = 2`, and define getter and setter on your class for it.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking really hard for that and as of Rails 7.0 it doesn't seem to be possible to eager load association joining it with a dynamic condition. It works with static conditions or you can join it and filter it with `where` (as other answers suggest) but there are certain use cases when both of these solutions don't fit and I don't think there's a workaround to make it work with ActiveRecord eager loading. You can only skip using ActiveRecord eager loading functionality altogether and make a separate raw SQL request and get data directly, something like:

```
sql = Restaurant.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN "reservations" ON "reservations"."restaurant_id" = "restaurants"."id" AND "reservations"."number_of_people" = ?', 2).select('restaurants.*, reservations.id as r_id').to_sql
rows = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
grouped = rows.group_by {|row| row['id'] }
records = grouped.map do |id, row|
  row_hash = row[0].except('r_id')
  restaurant = Restaurant.new(row_hash)

  reservations = row.map {|tt| tt['r_id'] }.map {|id| Reservation.new(id:) }
  restaurant.association(:reservations).target = reservations
end

# access filtered reservations:
restaurant.reservations.each { ... }
```

This is just a minimal example where I only set `id` of reservations, because I don't know what other columns you have on it but this approach allows you to add other fields to the `Reservation` instances too. This approach has it's caveats too, for instance AR instances created like that will have `persisted?` equal to `false` unless you explicitly reload them (which will make another SQL query). But as long is you don't care about `persisted?` value you should be fine.